# Why does this JWT have an unexpected value?

Tags: jwt

Here is a JWT I generated (without the signature):

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1NzIxMjA5MTQsImlkIjoyNjI0MTYwMDY5ODk3NDQxOSwibmJmIjoxNTY4NTIwOTE0LCJyb2xlIjowfQ
```

When I decode this JWT using https://jwt.io 's debugger, I get the following:

```
{"alg":"HS256","typ":"JWT"}
{"exp":1572120914,"id":26241600698974420,"nbf":1568520914,"role":0}
```

But decoding it in a Base64 decoder online (like [this](https://www.base64decode.net/) one) gives me this:

```
{"alg":"HS256","typ":"JWT"}
{"exp":1572120914,"id":26241600698974419,"nbf":1568520914,"role":0}
```

Notice the **id** is different. **26241600698974419** was the string used to generate the JWT. I can't reproduce this difference with any other id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That number is too big. It's a good practice to represent really large numbers as strings when working with json, especially because all numbers in javascript are technically floating points and not integers so they always lose precision when they exceed the [max safe integer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) - 9007199254740991. That decoder tool is probably decoding it server side in some other language and just displaying the entire result as a string, but I'd guess the JWT debugger is using Javascript, hence the difference.

Answer (score 1):

The id is syntactically a number in your JSON. Most implementations will use an IEEE double to represent numbers and there are simply too many digits to be represented exactly in a double. Make the id a string instead of a number, something like this:

```
"id":"26241600698974420"
```